# Is a bijective entire function uniformly continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

> Let $f$ be an entire function such that $f$ is bijective. Is then $f$ uniformly continuous?

I am thinking on this when trying to compute the analytic automorphisms $Aut(\Bbb C)$. I know that $Aut(\Bbb C)=\{f:\Bbb C\to \Bbb C\mid f(z)=az+b \,\text{with}\, a,b\in\Bbb C,a\neq 0\}$ and a uniformly continuous entire function is at most a linear polynomial. If this  result holds, then computing $Aut(\Bbb C)$ will be much easier to me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to show that a bijective entire function is of the form $az+b.$

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly pointed out, every automorphism of $\mathbb C$ is of the form $az+b$. Then, let $f$ be a non-constant automorphism:

$|f(z)-f(w)|=|az+b-(aw+b)|=|a||z-w| $. Now, let $|z-w| < \frac {\epsilon}{2|a||z-w|}$. Can we use a single value of $2|a||z-w|$ for all $z,w \in \mathbb C$ ? Hint: what happens with the value of |z-w| if we consider $2z,2w ; kz, kw, etc$?

Comment: Do not assume initially that $Aut(\Bbb C)$ are polynomials of degree 1. I want a direct proof that a bijective entire function is uniformly continuous.